# Python Move between rooms Key Error message

Tags: python, if-statement

```
rooms = {
        'Great Hall': {'South': 'Bedroom'},
        'Bedroom': {'North': 'Great Hall', 'East': 'Cellar'},
        'Cellar': {'West': 'Bedroom'}
}
current_room = 'Great Hall'



user_move = ''
directions = ['North', 'South', 'East', 'West']

while user_move != 'exit':
    print("You are in the", current_room)
    user_move = input("Choose a direction ")
    current_room = rooms[current_room][user_move]
    if user_move in current_room:
        print(current_room)
    else:
        print("Invalid move. Try again")
```

Hi all,
I am an extreme newbie to python and am having an issue with my if/else statement. I get a KeyError when I purposely put in an invalid direction to see the output. I am sure I am almost there but am brain dead at this point trying to figure it out.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to verify that the chosen direction is valid *before* moving rooms.

```
while user_move != 'exit':
    print("You are in the", current_room)
    user_move = input("Choose a direction ")

    # is the move a valid choice?
    if user_move in rooms[current_room]:
        # yes it is valid, so move there
        current_room = rooms[current_room][user_move]
        print(current_room)
    else:
        # no, it was not a valid move
        print("Invalid move. Try again")
```

Your code was moving rooms before checking if the direction was valid.

Comment: Thank you!! I knew it was something simple.